# Why correlation coefficient template matching perfoms better than cross-correlation and square-differences method

Tags: image-processing, opencv, cross-correlation, template-matching

I am using this template in OpenCv's match template function by converting all images to grayscale.

[image]

Here are my result using sum of square differences,cross correlation and correlation coefficient.Both SSD and Cros Correlation method fails matching but correlation coefficient performs well.

Not in this case but in my prior experience I always find cross correlation method the most robust one.I didn't understand why here correlation coefficient method works better than others ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What if you negate the images first?

Comment: why should I do this ?

Comment: I'm wondering if the white background has something to do with it.

Comment: If the correlation coefficient is not affected by white background,what is the reason behind it ?

Comment: There could be a difference in if/how subtraction of the mean and image normalization is done.